# How to hide my tor exit node from getting detected?

Tags: exit-relays

Some websites detect my exit node and understand i am using tor browser and won't let me in their websites. VPN's do not prevent it from happening. neither does proxies. What can i do to hide my true exit node and trick a website into believeing i am not a tor user?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with Tor alone. Some people combine Tor with other proxies/VPNs/etc for this reason, but in some circumstances this can harm anonymity. If it's a smaller website, you can try emailing them and ask them to support Tor users. Some websites don't know that they're blocking Tor.

Answer (score 1):

Tor exit nodes ips are public and can be easily found. They can be found at [dan.me.uk list](https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/?exit) or [Tor metrics with exit flag](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/flag:exit%20).
There is nothing you can do except for contacting site administrators and telling them to support connections from Tor (unlikely that they'll do it). If you still want to access the site, you can use a private proxy (you can use [proxychains](https://github.com/haad/proxychains) to chain your traffic through tor and then a private proxy).